# What type of information is required in TextureData contructor?

Tags: java, opengl, jogl

When trying to create a TextureData object in jogl, according to some documentation the contructor takes the following parameters:

```
TextureData(GLProfile glp,
int internalFormat, 
int width, 
int height, 
int border, 
int pixelFormat, 
int pixelType, 
boolean mipmap, 
boolean dataIsCompressed, 
boolean mustFlipVertically, 
Buffer buffer, 
TextureData.Flusher flusher)
```

"Constructs a new TextureData object with the specified parameters and data contain the given Buffer."

I can't find out what type of information is represented by the "pixelFormat" int, the "PixelType" int and the flusher. Can someone explain?

Comment: pixelFormat and pixelType are probably the same as the format and type parameters in glTexImage2D. https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glTexImage2D.xhtml

Comment: Have you look at its Java documentation? http://jogamp.org/deployment/jogamp-next/javadoc/jogl/javadoc/com/jogamp/opengl/util/texture/TextureData.html#TextureData%28javax.media.opengl.GLProfile,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20boolean,%20boolean,%20boolean,%20java.nio.Buffer,%20com.jogamp.opengl.util.texture.TextureData.Flusher%29 The flusher is optional and allows to release the native memory used by a TextureData object, it's typically used to destroy the direct NIO buffer. Can't you use TextureIO.newTextureData() in your case? user3256930 is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the type of image data you are giving GL.

For .png it's GL_RGBA and GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE.